# Preventing certain files from being pulled in git

Tags: git

I have some files that I want to be ignored via git pull on a remote machine. I still want it to be a working copy, for updating only the changes. On my local machine I don't want those files to be ignored.

I tried adding the files in .gitignore on the remote machine, but I guess it's only for commits.

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot - the point of git is you get a full copy of the repository - you are implementing the "I have a hammer so everything is a nail principle" and trying to make it do something is was never designed to do - I suggest you switch tools if the is a break all requirement.

If you do not want the file in the repo - do not add it.

If you want to control access to certain files - move them to a separate repo and restrict access.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. See, the files I want ignored are graphical source files, so I DO want them to be version controlled, I however don't need them on the server. So I guess my method of deploying is not the right one. How to do it better and still keep the "only update diff"-advantage?

Comment: Sorry it was a bit short - have you tried moving the file to a subrepo and make it part if the original so you can deny access to it. So maybe have a subrepo of images.git. Maybe reading http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules or http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging can help

Comment: Yes that might be an option but the submodule is still a separate repo, which is not ideal for me in this situation. Thanks anyway.